# Few questions about the algebraic cycles and the conjectures of Beilinson and Tate

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology, chow-groups

I have three slightly related questions about algebraic cycles which I am just going to list them. I'd really appreciate any answers:

1) Is there any example of a smooth projective variety $X$ over a finite field that is of dimension $n>1$ and at least for some $i>1$, $CH^i(X)$ the Chow group of co-dimension $i$ cycles is of rank greater than 1?

2) Let $X$ be like above. Is it known whether it is possible the intersection pairing between $CH^i(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ and $CH^{n-i}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ can be completely zero? The Beilinson's conjecture about coincidence of numerical and rational equivalences in this setting predicts this cannot happen, I am just wondering whether you can deduce this without assuming that conjecture. (For example if there is a line bundle that the top self-intersection is non-zero then this cannot happen.)

3) Beilinson-Tate conjecture predicts for the same $X$, $c^i:CH^i(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow H^{2i}(X,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}(i))$ is injective. Is it known whether this cannot be totally zero?

Comment: Concerning the first question, the full flag varieties would be examples where you can find $CH^i(X)$ with rank > 1.

Comment: For 3, the cycle map is nonzero for $i\le \dim X$, because the class of $D^i$ is nonzero when $D$ is an ample divisor.

Comment: And the same reasoning shows that the pairing in Q2 is nonzero. So I guess, this is completely answered.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt I'd really appreciate if you could point me to a paper that such calculations of rank are done. Thanks.

Comment: See Fulton's Intersection Theory for calculations of Chow groups of flag varieties. If you want something easier, look at $CH^i((\mathbb{P}^1)^n)$.

Comment: There are many papers and maybe even some MO-answers which describe the Chow ring of flag varieties. The flag varieties are cellular which means that all sorts of cycle class maps are isomorphisms. The easiest presentation of the Chow ring for $GL_n/B$ is as quotient of the polynomial ring in $n$ variables by the symmetric polynomials. The result is a graded abelian group of rank $n!$ and you can see that ranks in degrees $>1$ can become pretty big.